# Copy data from on-prem SQL server DB to Azure SQL DB. Then truncate the tables in Azure SQL DB after data is copy to Tableau CRM

Tags: triggers, azure-sql-database, tableau-api, azure-data-factory

I want to automate below tasks/scenario with the help of trigger or function. As of now performed these steps through Azure Data Factory by manually running the pipeline.

1. Copy data from on-prem sql server to Azure SQL DB automatically whenever new data is populated in on-prem sql db.
2. Truncate tables from Azure SQL DB whenever a pull request comes from Tableau CRM via Microsoft Azure SQL DB connector.

Don't want to include azure synapse analytics into picture.

Need you kind suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage **Copy Data tool** to Ingest data on schedule.

[image]

[image]

**Select your on-premise database as source**

[image]

**Note:** You would have to use self-hosted IR for source linked service (on-prem sql db). Refer: [Tutorial: How to access on-premises SQL Server from Data Factory Managed VNet using Private Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-managed-virtual-network-on-premise-sql-server)

**Select new rows only**

[image]

**Next, you can choose an existing table or create a new one with source table schema**

[image]

**Make customer requirements changes**

[image]

**Finally, validate and deploy!**

### And for truncating tables after copy...

There is a provision for **Stored Procedure** and **Pre-copy scripts** in `CopyActivty` though but you might have to use `explicit` **StoredProcedure Activity** after the **CopyActvity** to clear the tables

[image]

[image]

**OR.. Better**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Karthik for the wonderful answer. This will serves the purpose for scenario 1. Could you please help me with answer to the second scenario as listed in question.

Comment: Sure, but I did not understand that completely. You want to delete all tables from Azure sql db when you get pull request from Tableau? can explain that bit "`whenever a pull request comes from Tableau CRM via Microsoft Azure SQL DB connector.`"  not sure I've come across this before

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly. When Azure SQL DB get the pull request from a Tableau connector( in this case we use Microsoft Azure SQL DB connector). It should delete the data(not table) once the request is complete and the data gets populated in Tableau.


Also, coming to your answer for first scenario in the 3rd pic **"select new rows"**, In our case source table do not have a modified date column. what should be the next step to complete this copy activity.

Comment: I've added for the second bit in answer. You ought to have a column with datetime or timestamp to identify the new records created. You can alter the table to add them.

Comment: In the snip for example, I had my table with column name `ModifiedDate`, which stored the tmestamp when the row was inserted into the table. You can create a column that by default stores UTC timestamp when row is inserted. Example: `ALTER TABLE TestTable
ADD DateInserted DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE());`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This data is pulled from client on-prem db to Azure. I don't think we have a privilege to alter the schema(add columns) in the source tables.

Comment: I understand, but when you need to get only the updated rows, there has to be some way to identify right.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer definitely help me implement this solution. Just one last question if you can answer this too.  

Question: The pipeline you suggested will copy the data  and then the stored prod activity will delete the data once the pipeline execution is over. I can add a wait activity in between copy activity and stored proc activity to hold the pipeline execution for 'n' seconds by default. Suppose I need to hold the pipeline execution for 7 days before moving to stored proc. Can you pls suggest a dynamic content(dynamic query) that I can implement in wait activity.?
Thanks again K

Comment: you can use `add()` function from Math functions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#add

Comment: Parameterize it, create an `int` type parameter like this : `@add(10,pipeline().parameters.additionalSecs)` where 10 would be default and dynamically enter value to parameter as you like (in secs)